# During magento 2 import How to import some data from csv to custom table?

Tags: magento2

During the magento product import some of the data or column in csv file need to import in my custom table. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried something already, some sample of code? Then we can help you better!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Magento2 without customization.

You can create a custom module to add new import type and here are some steps to follow:
https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-import-csv-file-to-custom-table-magento2/